# In what type of structure can I save binary data from ifstream?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, binaryfiles, readfile

I have the following problem:

I need contents of binary file X, which I can read with `std::ifstream` but the problem is that I will need those in a loop which let's say looks like:

```
// pseudo code
while(true)
{
  var i = read 8 chars from ifstream(X)

  if (i == 0xaeae)
    read 10 bytes from ifstream(X)
  if (i == 0xaeff)
    read 20 bytes from ifstream(X)

  // other stuff
}
```

So the problem is that I would like to read the binary contents of file X to (preferrably) a (what type of?) stream so that I eleminate disc reads from the while loop.

What type of structure is applicable here and how to do it?

I know how to read that into e.g. `vector<char>`:

```
std::ifstream ifs("X", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> fileContents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
                               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

but this doesn't give me the `read(n bytes)` API

**EDIT**

My 'working' solution with `std::stringstream`:

```
std::filebuf fb;
std::stringstream data;
if (fb.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in))
{
  std::istream is(&fb);
  data<< std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  while (is)
    data << std::setw(2) << static_cast< int >(is.get());
  fb.close();
}
```

**EDIT2**

I got confused by my other solutions which didn't work so that's the upgraded version with `std::stringstream`:

```
std::ifstream is(filename.c_str());
std::stringstream data;
if (!is)
{
  // error
}
else
{
  data << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  while (is)
    data << std::setw(2) << static_cast< int >(is.get());
  is.seekg(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at copying the data into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)?

Comment: @NathanOliver I have  ready solution with this but I am not sure whether that's the best solution to copy binary data into a `std::stringstream`

Comment: I am not 100% sure either.  I was just asking if you had seen it.  since this question seems somewhat broad(i.e. asking for any type) to me maybe you could change it and ask if copying the file into a `std::stingstream` would be a good thing to do?

Comment: Oh I forgot about memory mapped files.  You may want to look into them.

Comment: Why the heck are you decouping the file buffer from the input stream? Just use `std::ifstream ifs{filename.c_str()}` and be done with it. that way, you also don’t need to close anything and omit the `if`. In other words, your solution gets >50% shorter.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right. I got confued by my other solutions which didn't work and I forgot about `std::ifstream`